# How to Set Log4j Properties Programmatically with Lombok

Tags: java, logging, log4j, lombok

Log4j allows me to easily setup logging with each class. I want to change properties of my JavaFX application on initialization. What I want to do is to create log files under user's `%appdata%/<app>/<version>` directory (for the sake of example). I found a [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) about programmatically set the properties of logger.

I have a very similar Log4j `ConfigurationFactory` as follows.

```
public class Log4jConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {
    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[] {"*"};
    }

    private static Configuration createConfiguration(final String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        builder.setConfigurationName(name);
        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.DEBUG);

        builder.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).
                addAttribute("level", Level.DEBUG));
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").
                addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").
                addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newFilter("MarkerFilter", Filter.Result.DENY,
                Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).addAttribute("marker", "FLOW"));

        builder.add(appenderBuilder);
        builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", Level.DEBUG).
                add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")).
                addAttribute("additivity", false));
        builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource source) {
        return getConfiguration(loggerContext, source.toString(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final String name, final URI configLocation) {
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
        return createConfiguration(name, builder);
    }
}
```

And I have a main class as below:

```
@Log4j2
public class App extends GenericApplication { // this GenericApplication extends Application, it is from a library I use, no worries.
    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        super.init();
        log.debug("Hey."); // for testing purposes
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        super.start(primaryStage);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        log.error("Hey."); // for testing purposes
    }

    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        GenericApplication.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The problem is that Log4j *naturally* does not find my custom `Log4jConfigurationFactory`. It seems Lombok does not have `Log4j` annotation to provide a custom `ConfigurationFactory` (according to its [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/log), the only argument `Log` annotation might have is `topic` purpose of which is to give a human-readable (?) `Logger` title.).

So, how do I use custom `ConfigurationFactory` with Lombok?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

```
Group ID: org.projectlombok
Artifact ID: lombok
Version: 1.16.20

Group ID: org.apache.logging.log4j
Artifact ID: log4j-core
Version: 2.11.0
```